# Digital PID velocity controller

Tags: pid-controller

I have seen two differente digital PID controller so far and I don't know which one should be prefered to control the speed of a dc motor.

1.) out=out_last + Kp err + Ki sum_err + Kd (err-err_last)

2.) out=Kp*err + Ki*sum_err + Kd*(err-err_last)

The first one seems to be very slow for a variing reference signal, but achieves a good velocity control. The second one i cannot stabilize.

Which one should normally be prefered in the implementation of a speed controller on a uC?

Edit: I found a new approach for velocity control from here: https://www.controleng.com/single-article/the-velocity-of-pid/0733c0b7bfa474fb659b259808ddc869.html

Can I implement this on a uC in the form:
$$
out_n=K_p*e_n + K_v*(e_n - e_{n-1}) + K_a*((e_n-e_{n-1})-(e_{n-1}-e_{n-2}))
$$

Where in the last term the $$e_{n-1}$$ cancels. Or how should I implement the second derivative on a uC?

Comment: The first one is a PID controller *followed by an integrator*, which fundamentally changes the behaviour of the controller; the D term becomes a proportional term, the P term becomes an integral term and the I term becomes a double integral.

Comment: where did you get this from? what does each term mean?  the 1st one looks like a positive feedback system (last output added to scaled input...) The 2nd looks closer to a classic PID (be it with a poor integral difference equation) and then its a matter of tuning

Comment: I cannot remeber where I found it, it was some years ago and I recently had a look at my code from then. Out means the output, err means the error between the reference signal and the output.